# ASP.NET Core served stopped

Tags: asp.net, deployment, asp.net-core

I have problem with my asp.net Core app. Application after few minutes stoped. And my jobs in quartz are lost. I read someware the .net core app never stoped so why I have problem with it? My Program.cs include code to use Kestrel:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

I publish app with standard deployment in visual studio.

Comment: Are you using Azure App Service? Or IIS? To less information to help you.

Comment: I use polish hosting `https://www.webio.pl` i hosted there standard .net applications so i think they use IIS

Comment: Kestrel itself doesn't recycle, IIS does. No matter if it is ASP.NET core or ASP.NET application

Comment: So if I dont want a recycle i haave to use Kestrel. How i can configure my app to use it?

Comment: You shall **NOT** use Kestrel for IFS, it's not supported. Kestrel is not meant to directly expose its content to the internet. You have to run it behind a Webproxy, **always**. In windows that reverse proxy typically is IIS under linux nginx (or less common Apache/lighttpd)

Answer (score 2):

IIS/Azure App Service (runs IIS in behind too) recycle your application pool after some time of idle and/or when the server runs low on resources. The statement of not recycling only applies to Kestrel, usually on Linux behind nginx, as its not recommended to use Kestrel as IFS (Internet Facing Server).

While you can set the idle time up and a warmup phase, there is no guarantee it won't stop due to low resources.

**Never** run Background Tasks inside ASP.NET/Webapplication. Always use a console application or windows service for reoccurring tasks.

Comment: I have to use Background tanks becouse my app after get some data need to wait 4 minutes and do something. This is only 4 minutes but when I get request like that: 5 request - 1 mb 2 minutes wait and next 5 request. My server shouldnt stop i think this is only maximum 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, but don't use ASP.NET Core for it. Make a console application or a windows service which does it. In a web application you should never rely on the fact that it will run continuously

Comment: @Tseng: this is what [hangfire](http://hangfire.io) is about, it's a background task scheduler for asp.net and asp.net core. It's been around for a while and works great. You should mention it at least rather than blindly recommend windows services as an alternative.

Comment: Like I said, Web application (no matter if ASP.NET Core, ASP.NET or Java) are can not be relied to run continuously. It's like playing roulette. The correct way is to do it in a background service (i..e console application)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx describes on how to set idle time up or down in IIS7 (similar for other IIS versions should be there), but still even then: YOU HAVE NO GUARANTEE that IIS **WON'T** recycle it. You will **never** have it, so its best **not to rely on it**. It is how IIS and (managed) application servers work in general